# Display Loading spinner whilst data is fetching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

How can show a loading spinner whilst the data is loading to fetch.

```js
const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);
const navigate = useNavigate()
const [bikes] = useBikes()

if (loading) {
  return  <Loading></Loading>
}
            
fetch(`http://localhost:5000/bike/${id}`, {
    method: 'DELETE'
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
      alert('One Item Deleted')
   });
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the spinner under the id `spinner` here's a minimalistic example on how you can do so. just wrap the fetch inside a function.

```js
function delitem(){
  document.getElementByID("spinner").style.display = "block"
  fetch(`http://localhost:5000/bike/${id}`, {
    method: 'DELETE'
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
      alert('One Item Deleted')
      document.getElementByID("spinner").style.display = "none"
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your fetch API inside the useEffect, so you can easily implement your spinner functionality

```
const [isLoading,setIsLoading]=useState(false);


useEffect(()=>{
 setIsLoading(true);
 fetch("some-url").then(res=>res.json())
  .then(data=>{
  setIsLoading(false)
  console.log(data);
},[])

if(isLoading){
 return <LoadingSpinner/>
}

return <div>..your data </div>
```